# How is.integer() works in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of numerics,integers and string. I would like to check which columns are integers and I do

```
raw<-read.csv('./rawcorpus.csv',head=F)
ints<-sapply(raw,is.integer)
```

anyway this gives me all false. So I have to make a little change

```
nums<-sapply(raw,is.numeric)
ints2<-sapply(raw[,nums],function(col){return(!(sum(col%%1)==0))})
```

The second case works fine. My question is: what is actually checking the 'is.integer' function?

Comment: It checks if a vector is of type `integer`. If it returns `FALSE` your data.frame columns are not integers. Try `sapply(raw, class)` to see the column classes. Or use `str`.

Comment: `is.integer()` is related to the result of `typeof()`.  See the help file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, R will store all numbers as double precision floating points, i.e., the `numeric`. Three useful functions `class`, `typeof` and `storage.mode` will tell you how a value is stored. Try:

```
x <- 1
class(x)
typeof(x)
storage.mode(x)
```

If you want `x` to be integer 1, you should do with **suffix** "L"

```
x <- 1L
class(x)
typeof(x)
storage.mode(x)
```

Or, you can cast numeric to integers by:

```
x <- as.integer(1)
class(x)
typeof(x)
storage.mode(x)
```

**The `is.integer` function checks whether the storage mode is integer or not.** Compare

```
is.integer(1)
is.integer(1L)
```

You should be aware that some functions actually return `numeric`, even if you expect it to return `integer`. These include `round`, `floor`, `ceiling`, and mod operator `%%`.

Comment: `type.convert` recognizes integers just fine: `x <- read.table(text = "1\n2"); str(x)`. If OP had (only) integers in a column, they should be stored as integers after import.

Answer (score 1):

From R documentation:

*is.integer(x) does not test if x contains integer numbers! For that, use round, as in the function is.wholenumber(x) in the examples.*

So in is.integer(x), x must be a vector and if that **contains** integer numbers, you will get true. In your first example, argument is a number, not a vector

Hope that helps

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/integer.html