# R- Difference betwen c(1:6) and c(1,2,3,4,5,6) in the case of typeof() function?

Tags: r

I know that R will save any number that we type as "double" by default. But if I run the following codes, it is giving me two different answers

**CODE 1**

```
die <- c(1:6)
typeof(die)
```

OUTPUT1:-[1] "integer"

**CODE 2**

```
die <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
typeof(die)
```

OUTPUT2:-[2] "double"

So Please clarify me why this "integer" if I use c(1:6) and "double" if directly specify all the elements in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)`, you will get "integer" rather than "double". Just compare `tyoeof(1)` and `typeof(1L)`. Or you may read my answer here: [How does `is.integer` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258870/4891738).

`1:6` is short for `seq.int(1, 6)`, so you get a vector in integer storage mode.

```
typeof(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L))
# [1] "integer"

typeof(1:6)
# [1] "integer"

typeof(seq.int(1, 6))
# [1] "integer"
```